# how to know if need to run e2fsck in order to fix corrupted blocks?

Tags: linux, redhat, hard-drive, filesystems, e2fsck

We want to check the filesystem on the disks as `/deb/sdc`  ... `/dev/sdg` on each Red Hat Linux machine.

The target is to find what are the disks that require `e2fsck` ( as `e2fsck -y /dev/sdb` etc.)

According to man page

> `-n`
>   Open  the filesystem read-only, and assume an answer of 'no' to all questions.  Allows `e2fsck` to be used non-interactively.  This option may not be specified at the same time as the `-p` or `-y` options.

When we run the command (example)

```
 e2fsck -n /dev/sdXX
```

we get

> ```
> e2fsck 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
> Warning!  /dev/sdc is mounted.
> Warning: skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only filesystem check.
> /dev/sdc: clean, 94/1310720 files, 156685/5242880 blocks
> ```

So what do we need to capture from `e2fsck -n` output, that requires us to run `e2fsck` (without `-n`)?

**e2fsck process**

```
init 1
umount /dev/sdXX
e2fsck -y /dev/sdXX  # (or e2fsck -C /dev/sdXX for full details) 
init 3
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: very simple - I want to find the disks that required e2fsck , ( on other words - which output we should capture from e2fsck -n    in order to know if this is bad disk or good disk )

Comment: Why not try this on a test system, as described in John Mahowald's answer? You need to account for multiple failure modes, so you should really test those scenarios by reproducing them in a test environment. You could also do some research into ext* filesystems to answer your own questions. `e2fsck` has a huge amount of readily available documentation that will cover the scenarios you describe, as well as equip you to act on the information it provides. If you're so concerend with online detection of block level corruption and actually want the ability to repair it, look at BTRFS.

Comment: You should use the database function for detecting corruption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RHEL boot scripts will `fsck` on each boot. Rebooting for this purpose accomplishes the same thing as your procedure to switch to single user mode.

You know the file system journal is not clean if booting hangs because `fsck` is waiting for input. It will tell you not clean and prompt for any repairs made.

You can force a check with `touch /forcefsck`  and reboot.

Edit: You have to umount to properly fsck, per below from the `e2fsck` man page. You also need to ommit -n "no" option when you want to repair the file systems.

> Note  that  in  general  it  is  not safe to run e2fsck on mounted
>   filesystems.  The only exception is if the -n option is specified, and
>   -c, -l, or -L options are not specified. However, even if it is safe to do so, the results printed by e2fsck are not valid if the
>   filesystem is mounted.   If e2fsck asks whether or not  you  should 
>   check  a  filesystem which is mounted, the only correct answer is
>   'no'.

You don't have to reboot to do this, it just is convenient.  If the downtime for your services is problem for you, bring a copy of the data online on a different storage system while repairing this one. Also known as put your business continuity plan in place.

To see a real unclean fsck on a test system:

1. Backup any data you care about.
2. Start a write workload such as a storage benchmark with `fio`
3. Crash the system hard. On Linux, try`echo 'c' > /proc/sysrq-trigger`

Comment: hi , we want to verify the disks without reboot the OS , this is the reason that I want to use e2fsck -n  option , and my goal is to capture the "bad" results from command - is it possible ?  , second we want to verify the non OS disks , see please my update question

Comment: Technically, no. You can umount and fsck file systems.  This requires shutting down services too so you might as well reboot.  See my edit.